# Biber Not Recognizing key

Tags: biblatex, biber, apa-style, apa7

Biber refuses to recognize the second entry of my bibliography.

```
@online{adhdcontroversy,
    title = {Controversies Surrounding ADHD},
    url = {https://www.mentalhelp.net/adhd/controversies/},
    date = {2020}
}
@article{adhd2018,
     title = {Twenty-Year Trends in Diagnosed Attention-Deficit/Hyperactivity Disorder Among US Children and Adolescents, 1997-2016},
     author = {Xu, Guifeng and Strathearn, Lane and Liu, Buyon and Yang, Binrang and and Bao, Wei},
     date = {2018},
     url = {https://jamanetwork.com/journals/jamanetworkopen/fullarticle/2698633},
     doi = {doi:10.1001/jamanetworkopen.2018.1471}
}
```

In the following test document

```tex
\documentclass[stu,draftall,biblatex,hidelinks]{apa7}

\addbibresource{sources.bib}

\title{info}
\author{info info}
\affiliation{info info}
\course{info info}
\professor{info info}
\duedate{23\textsuperscript{rd} of January, 2022}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\parencite{adhd2018}\\
\cite{adhdcontroversy}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

### Steps to reproduce

1. Place latex above in a .tex file.
2. Place bib file above in `sources.bib`
3. Compile via pdfLaTeX
4. Run Biber
5. Compile via pdfLaTeX again

Result:

[image: Sources Not Working]

Comment: You might want to look in the `bibler` log (it'd a file with ending `.blg` There is a `and and` in that entry

Comment: After fixing the double `and` the code works fine for me. Tip: via `\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{sources.bib} ... \end{filecontents}` you can include the `.bib` into your example making it easier to test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever there is a problem with the bibliography, have a look at Biber's log file (the file ending in `.blg` - which despite what Windows may want to tell you is just a simple text file). In this example, the file contains, amongst other

```
[418] Utils.pm:395> WARN - Name in key 'adhd2018' is empty (probably consecutive 'and'): skipping entry 'adhd2018'
[418] Utils.pm:395> WARN - Entry with key 'adhd2018' in section '0' is cited and found but not created (likely due to sourcemap)
[446] Utils.pm:395> WARN - BibTeX subsystem: substring 5, warning: empty substring
```

There is an error in the `author` field of `adhd2018`. It is

```
 author = {Xu, Guifeng and Strathearn, Lane and Liu, Buyon and Yang, Binrang and and Bao, Wei},
```

with `and and` where `and` would be enough.

```
 author = {Xu, Guifeng and Strathearn, Lane and Liu, Buyon and Yang, Binrang and Bao, Wei},
```

Fix this error and rerun Biber and then pdfLaTeX.

---

Independent of this issue you may want to use curly braces to protect abbreviations and other words in the title that may not be changed to lowercase (like ADHD and US).

The `doi` field should not contain the string `doi:` at the beginning.

```
\documentclass[stu,draftall,biblatex,hidelinks]{apa7}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@online{adhdcontroversy,
  title = {Controversies Surrounding {ADHD}},
  url   = {https://www.mentalhelp.net/adhd/controversies/},
  date  = {2020}
}
@article{adhd2018,
  title  = {Twenty-Year Trends in Diagnosed
            Attention-Deficit/Hyperactivity Disorder
            Among {US} Children and Adolescents, 1997-2016},
  author = {Xu, Guifeng and Strathearn, Lane and Liu, Buyon
            and Yang, Binrang and Bao, Wei},
  date   = {2018},
  url    = {https://jamanetwork.com/journals/jamanetworkopen/fullarticle/2698633},
  doi    = {10.1001/jamanetworkopen.2018.1471}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\title{info}
\author{info info}
\affiliation{info info}
\course{info info}
\professor{info info}
\duedate{23\textsuperscript{rd} of January, 2022}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\parencite{adhd2018}

\cite{adhdcontroversy}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image: working bibliography]